# Python Newbie error creating Block

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, python-idle

I was going through a Python Tutorial and it covered creating a block of code.

Here's the tutorial code:

```
name = "Doug"
if name == 'Doug':
  print "Hello, D-man!"
print "How are you today?
```

When I try doing the same in Python IDLE:

```
>>> if name == "Doug":
    print "Hello, D-man!"
print "How are you today?"
```

IDLE gives me an exception:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

I read about indentation online but I'm unable to figure it out.
I know this is a basic question request but please help, as I am still a newbie.

Comment: In the shell, you need to leave an extra blank line after the indented block - otherwise it doesn't know when you've finished the block. This doesn't happen in a normal script.

Comment: It would help to post the entire idle session verbatim. You seem to be using a very old tutorial for python 2 (the print statement gives it away). In python3, `print` is now a function: `print("Hello, D-man!")`. If you are using `idle` from python 3, yeah, its a syntax error. You really _do_ want to use python 3, so find a newer tutorial!

Comment: Please find below Idle session.    Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.

>>> name = "Doug"
>>> if name == "Doug":
 print"Hello, D-man!"
 print "How are you today?"
 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: yes I am using the 2 but it would be great if anyone have the 3.0 tutorial I can start using that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in shell you have to do each block separately. If you want it to work in shell you are going to have to do:

```
>>> if name == "Doug":
        print "Hello, D-man!"
```

And then:

```
>>> print "How are you today?"
```

Although I would suggest simply selecting **New File** from the File menu of IDLE which should open up a new blank window that's called untitled.py. Here you can actually write your code so that it works as:

```
name = "Doug"
if name == 'Doug':
  print "Hello, D-man!"
print "How are you today?
```

Whenever you want to run it simply save it to your computer then go to the drop down menu Run and select **Run Module** or use the shortcut F5 and the file should then run back in the Shell.